# I/O file not getting opened

Tags: python, csv, io

I have this csv file dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/tb4yc3lm3gg3j22/out.csv and I am trying to replace the last column with the read method below.
In my input.csv i have to replace the last filed with some calculation. I trying as below but somehow i am getting   ValueError: I/O operation on a closed file. Can you help me point out the mistake. As i am trying to open input file and write everything including the new value to out.csv file which doesnt exist initially but should be constructed on the fly.

```
def read():
    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            fNameFull = os.path.basename(file)
            inputFileName = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
            with open(fNameFull, "rb") as infile, open('out.csv', "wb") as outfile:
                r = csv.DictReader(infile)
                w = csv.DictWriter(outfile, r.fieldnames)
                w.writeheader()
                for row in r:
                    if not row["col_last"].strip():
                        row["col_last"] = "calc_value"
                    w.writerow(row)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    read()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\final\text\finalmod.py", line 50, in <module>
    read()
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\final\text\finalmod.py", line 39, in read
    w.writeheader()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\csv.py", line 137, in writeheader
    self.writerow(header)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\csv.py", line 148, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Comment: This can happen if you've mixed tabs and spaces. The program looks fine, but python thinks you've dedented.

Comment: sorry i  mean the previous error went away but now i am getting another.
Any suggestion. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\final\text\finalmod.py", line 46, in <module>
    read()
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\final\text\finalmod.py", line 38, in read
    w.writeheader()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\csv.py", line 136, in writeheader
    header = dict(zip(self.fieldnames, self.fieldnames))
TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration

@tdelaney:  also once when it ran properly it just wrote the last line to out.csv with the substitution.

Comment: @miku please **edit the question** to include a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code and the full error traceback. Have you checked what `r.fieldnames` gives you?

Comment: sure. I have this csv file https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/tb4yc3lm3gg3j22/out.csv  and I am trying to replace the last column 'r9' with the read method i shared above. It is working fine after tdelaney's suggestion but writing only the last line in out.csv

Comment: Its likely a problem with r.fieldnames which should be some iterable that returns field name strings. Print it out right before you do `w = csv.DictWriter(outfile, r.fieldnames)` to see what it says.

Comment: oops... took a closer look. it definately is r.fieldnames. The writer needs something like a list or tuple where order is preserved so that it knows the order to write the columes. fieldnames is a dict and its keys are not ordered.

Comment: but fieldnames are coming properly, the data is getting overwritten it seems and only last line of input file is present in the output file

Comment: @tdelaney: any suggestion for change? :)

Comment: You keep overwriting out.csv with `open('out.csv', "wb")`. I notice you calculate `inputFileName` but don't use it. Do you mean to create a new output file per input file, like `open(inputFileName + '-out.csv', "wb")`?

Comment: yes i want to create one output file for each csv i read as input, but will open(inputFileName + '-out.csv', "wb") not do the same overwrite? should i open the file in append mode instead?

Comment: yes, it will overwrite, but only once per execution of your script... which is usually what you want. if you have a.csv and b.csv, on the first run of the script, you'll get a-out.csv and b-out.csv. If you run the script again, and use 'wb', you'll get completely new a-out.csv and b-out.csv, with just 1 copy of the original rows. If you use 'ab', a-out.csv and b-out.csv will now have the stuff from the original files twice. You can choose either way, depending on what you want.

Comment: @tdelaney: i used open(inputFileName + '-out.csv', "wb") but getting only one line in out.csv which is the last line of input.csv but i need whole data from input.csv..sorry if my question is still vague

Comment: Maybe you still have tabs in there... put `print file, len(row)` right before `w.writerow(row)` to see if you get a bunch of prints. If your code has changed, you could post the new stuff below the current.